# jQuery - how to call method/prototype function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sidebar

I am using sticky sidebar to make my sidebar(s) stick: http://github.com/caphun/jquery.stickysidebar/ I also use AJAX to reload the page many times. After a while, the scrolling lags and I presume it is because each time I reload the content without destroying the stickysidebar.

How do I call the destroy function here?

I tried

> $('.stickem').stickySidebar.destroy();

and

> $('.stickem').stickySidebar("destroy");

but neither worked. Here is the prototype:

> $.stickySidebar.prototype = {
>
> init: function() {
>
> ```
> // code
> ```
>
> },
>
> stickiness: function() {
>
> ```
> //code
> ```
>
> },
>
> bind: function() {  },
>
> destroy: function() {
>         alert('h');
>         this.element.unbind("destroyed", this.teardown);
>         this.teardown();
>     },
>
> teardown: function() {
>          console.log('eee');
>          $.removeData(this.element[0], this.name);
>          this.element.removeClass(this.name);
>          this.unbind();
>          this.element = null;
>     },
>
> unbind: function() {  }
>
> }

Comment: try this `var sidebar = $('.stickem').stickySidebar()` and then `sidebar.destroy()`

Comment: Thanks Max but it returns "undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you do jQuery plugins. If you want to call it as `$('.stickem').stickySidebar("destroy");` (which is the recommended way), do this:

```
$.fn.stickySidebar = function(action) {
    if (action === 'destroy') {
        ...
    }
};
```

See http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Thanks! But in the plugin code (https://github.com/caphun/jquery.stickysidebar/blob/master/jquery.stickysidebar.js) they wrote it first as a function like you did, but then all the other functions are in a "prototype" which I am not sure how to access.. I am not interested in rewriting the whole plugin, just need a way to destroy it/all the memory associated with it once I reload the page/content.

Comment: Confusingly, that link has 2 functions with same name: `$.fn.stickySidebar` and `$.stickySidebar`. `$.stickySidebar` is called on line 28, as constructor (i.e. with `new`). This means all elements of `$.stickySidebar.prototype` become elements of all objects constructed like this, such as `this` on lines 46 and 60 and `self` on line 70. Therefore, these lines call the methods `init`, `initValues` and `stickiness`, which are defined in `$.stickySidebar.prototype`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_Objects

Comment: Thanks for the responses David! Much appreciated. I read over the article, but still not sure how I would call a destroy function. If I ran the constructor like this: $('.sticky').stickySidebar(); how would I call a function inside the prototype or is there some other way to remove all data associated with the plugin? I tried removeData() as well but kept on getting "undefined function" error. tia

Comment: Line 66 binds a handler to the `window` object every time the script is run. If `window` is a persistent object, this means it adds more and more handlers, and all of them run every time you resize or scroll. There's no `destroy` function, and the author hasn't done anything about this. The best fix I can see is to run `$(window).off('resize.stickySidebar scroll.stickySidebar')` before calling `$('.stickem').stickySidebar()`; that should remove handlers that were set during the previous page load. (I haven't tested this.)

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much David Knipe for your help and patience and for sticking with my question for days. Your help is appreciated much more than the SO points I can award to you. Thanks again.